# Resolve regular expression issue; validate js

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have following issue in jquery.validate.js, I figure out issue in console is due to following statement:

```
!"Specializations[d6cec914-45dc-4b66-877b-98eca23ba543].IsChecked-error".match(new RegExp("\b" + "Specializations[d6cec914-45dc-4b66-877b-98eca23ba543].IsChecked-error"+ "\b" ))
```

I have change values for you guys.

I got error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid range in character class
```

There could be something with '-', but i have not much knowledge of regex. What can I try next?

Comment: escape your `[` and `]`.put `\\[` and `\\]`

Comment: @vks: best use `\\[` and `\\]`: OP is passing string to the `RegExp` constructor, the backslash needs escaping, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `[` and `]` characters in the string, as they are used to make character sets in regular expressions:

```
new RegExp("\b" + "Specializations\\[d6cec914-45dc-4b66-877b-98eca23ba543\\].IsChecked-error"+ "\b" )
```

Comment: can i have expression to replace those braces ? :p

Comment: @Aaron: Yes, you can use `.replace(/[/g, '\\[').replace(/]/g,'\\[')` on any string that you want to use in the regular expression. There are however other characters that would need replacing also, depending on what the string might contain.

Comment: thanks for help, though  expression in comment is not working as expecting but will accept answer asap.

Comment: @Aaron: My bad, those needs escaping there too. :) Here: `.replace(/\[/g, '\\[').replace(/\]/g,'\\[')`.

Answer (score 1):

The characters "[" and "]" are meta characters in Regular Expression which has especial meaning and cannot be used as regular character in a pattern.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

[ ]. A bracket expression. Matches a single character that is contained within the brackets. For example, [abc] matches "a", "b", or "c". [a-z] specifies a range which matches any lowercase letter from "a" to "z". These forms can be mixed: [abcx-z] matches "a", "b", "c", "x", "y", or "z", as does [a-cx-z].
The - character is treated as a literal character if it is the last or the first (after the ^, if present) character within the brackets: [abc-], [-abc]. Note that backslash escapes are not allowed. The ] character can be included in a bracket expression if it is the first (after the ^) character: []abc].